# Почему не работает webhook для телеграмм бота на aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, nginx, aiogram, aiohttp

Задача - заставить телеграмм бота, написанного на aiogram (python), работать на Webhook. Вроде все сделал, но бот не работает. Расскажу по порядку, чтобы было прощу понять где я ошибся или что-то пропустил:

Для начала арендовал VDS на Ubuntu 20.04 (***предположим его IP-адрес 50.60.70.80***) и арендовал доменное имя (***предположим имя domain123.ru***), связав его с IP-адресом VDS.

Далее по ssh подключился к VDS. Нижеуказанной командой установил nginx:

```
sudo apt install nginx
```

Далее включил встроенный firewall:

```
sudo ufw enable
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? y
```

Далее открыл для Nginx порты 80, 443 и порт 3001:

```
sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
sudo ufw allow 3001
sudo ufw allow 3001/tcp
```

Проверил работает ли ngxinx:

```
systemctl status nginx
```

В ответ получил, что статус Active (running).

Далее установил сертификат при помощи certbot (*он же letsencrypt*) по этой [инструкции](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=ubuntufocal). Все прошло успешно и были созданы файлы с сертификатом и приватным ключом в директориях:

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain123.ru/fullchain.pem
/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain123.ru/privkey.pem
```

Проверил, работает ли сервер, пройдя по всем возможным ссылкам:

1. *http:// 50.60.70.80*
2. *https://50.60.70.80*
3. *http:// domain123.ru*
4. *https://domain123.ru*

При каждом переходе выдавалась стартовая страница Nginx, что, как я понимаю, говорит о том, что сервер работает:

> Welcome to nginx! If you see this page, the nginx web server is
> successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.
>
> For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
> Commercial support is available at nginx.com.
>
> Thank you for using nginx.

В файл конфигурации Nginx (*nginx.conf*) добавил следующее (*не особо понимая что это, нагуглил на просторах интернета*):

```
server {
                listen 80;
                listen 443 ssl;
                server_name domain123.ru www.domain123.ru;

                ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
                ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain123.ru/fullchain.pem;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain123.ru/privkey.pem;
                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
                        proxy_redirect     off;
                        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                }
        }
```

Далее в директории root на том же VDS где установил Nginx создал python-файл echobot.py запускающий эхо-бота согласно документации библиотеки aiogram. Вот его содержимое:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.dispatcher.webhook import SendMessage
from aiogram.utils.executor import start_webhook


# webhook settings
WEBHOOK_HOST = 'https://domain123.ru' # доменное имя, которое я арендовал и привязал к серверу
WEBHOOK_PATH = '/this_path_not_exist/123' # уникальный выдуманный несуществующий путь
WEBHOOK_URL = f"{WEBHOOK_HOST}{WEBHOOK_PATH}"

# webserver settings
WEBAPP_HOST = 'localhost'  # or ip
WEBAPP_PORT = 3001

API_TOKEN = '1231231231:AAFWEZRSdfsaSDFHABSshb123123'
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
dp.middleware.setup(LoggingMiddleware())

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(text=message.text)

async def on_startup(dp):
    print('БОТ ЗАПУЩЕН!')
    await bot.set_webhook(WEBHOOK_URL)

async def on_shutdown(dp):
    await bot.delete_webhook()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_webhook(
        dispatcher=dp,
        webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
        on_startup=on_startup,
        on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
        skip_updates=True,
        host=WEBAPP_HOST,
        port=WEBAPP_PORT,
    )
```

Далее перехожу в директорию, где лежит файл с ботом и запускаю его командой:

```
python3 echobot.py
```

Бот запускается без ошибок и в терминал выдается следующая информация:

```
Updates were skipped successfully
БОТ ЗАПУЩЕН!
======== Running on http://localhost:3001 ========
```

Однако при отправке сообщения в бота он никак не реагирует - бот просто не видит апдейты, и соответственно никак не реагирует. Что я делаю не так? Какую ошибку допускаю или быть может пропускаю другие важные шаги? Помогите плиз, третий день гуглю все что можно, но так и не и нашел толкового мануала как ставить webhook на aiogram на своей VDS...

Comment: Посмотрите ошибки в логах. Но сдается мне что вы не выполнили `nginx -t && nginx -s reload`

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, при попытки ввода `nginx -t && nginx -s reload` терминал выдает:

Comment: `nginx: [emerg] server directive is not allowed here /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:87` и `nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed` .  Что не так?